# Pushing molten metal through 0.1 mm hole

Tags: thermodynamics, metals

is it possible to push molten metal (eg, titanium), through 0.1mm bore and what would be the force required for a steady & consistent stream of metal?
Any mathematical formulas/theory is good.

Comment: The viscosity of the fluid will depend on the temperature, so the force required will also vary.

Comment: Potentially relevant data is in https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.1515/HTMP.2008.27.6.401/pdf

Comment: What is the exact geometry, heating and/or insulating conditions,and molten metal viscosity vs temperature?